# Cannot load images into an m x n x p array due to size mismatch

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to add all the images from a folder into a `m * n * p` array. I know that the size of the images are not the same and are different from one another. And that is why I am getting a size mismatch error.

Here is the code I am trying to run

```
d = dir('c:\test\*.jpg');
fileNames = {d.name};
numElements = numel(fileNames);

Im =imread(fullfile('c:\test\',fileNames{1}));
I = rgb2gray(Im);

sequence = zeros([size(I) numElements], class(I));
sequence(:,:,1) = I;

for k = 2:numElements
    sequence(:,:,k) = rgb2gray(imread(fullfile('c:\test\',fileNames{k})));
end
```

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

I tried to resize them using [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imresize.html) but that would either resize them based on scale, which would still not solve my problem or have them resized based on number of columns and rows which would ruin the aspect ratio.

Is there any way to initialize the `sequence` array so that it accepts images of any size and adjusts accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply resizing an image by padding or clipping seems crazy to me, unless you don't care if you lose information, or add zeros, which may significantly distort what the image means. (For SOME problems, that zero pad could be a problem.)

Up or downsampling can also lose information, or add unwanted features to an image due to the interpolation. I suppose that an intelligent choice of interpolant will not be a BAD idea, but that choice depends on what these images mean to you and how you will use them. Only you know those things. And of course, changing the aspect ratio is probably a poor idea.

If you just wish to store the images, then why not just use a cell array? Cell arrays don't care what size the images are.

If you REALLY need the images the same size, yet are unwilling to accept changes in aspect ratio, then zero padding is your only choice. Note that a zero-pad is effectively a black pixel pad. If you prefer to pad with white pixels, then pad with ones (or 255, depending on the scaling of your image.)

Edit:

Since a cell array seems to be the good solution, do it something like this:

```
% Preallocates a cell array
sequence = cell(6,1);

% stuff the images
for k = 1:numElements
    sequence{k} = rgb2gray(imread(fullfile('c:\test\',fileNames{k})));
end
```

Note that you are using a cell array already for the filenames. You index into a cell array using curly {} brackets. Be careful, as you CAN also index a cell array using round () parens, but the result of that will be a new cell array, not the actual cell element you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. It appears cell array may be the only option for me as I dont want to resize them. But Im having trouble as to how to load them up into the array. When I write ``sequence = cell(numElements)`` I get a 6 by 6 cell, having 36 empty matrices. I don't need that much. Then after this I cannot access the cell using for indexing. Is there a way to initialize a row only cell such as a vector. And then how do I load data into it? Thank you

Comment: So you want to use a 6x1 array. Use cell(6,1) to preallocate a 6x1 cell array. I'll do an edit to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two simple solutions, involving either padding or clipping of the original images to achieve a uniform size:

(1) decide on specific final dimensions in pixels for all images (for instance use one image as template for all others)

(2) **Alternative A.** Resize all of the images so that the size of one of the dimensions matches the corresponding one in the template, and the other is *bigger* than that of the template. Next clip the image along the oversized dimension. One alternative, seam carving, uses an algorithm that removes what it regards as non-essential pixels.

**Alternative B.** Resize all of the images so that the size of one of the dimensions matches the corresponding one in the template, and the other is *smaller* than that of the template. Pad the image along the short dimension so that it matches the size of the template.

If you cannot afford to lose any information from your images due to clipping then pad the images to size, but then whitespace will be present which may not be acceptable.